# How to create a Java Object for the nested json Using POjo class

Tags: java, json

I am facing issue in generating java object for this sample nested json format

```
{
"Id":"id1",
"Eid":"eid1",
"tar":"pro",
"highlights":[{
  "name":"l-p"
  "Data":{
       "dataid":"did1"
       }
     },
{
  "name":"c-p",
  "Data":{
       "dataid":"did2"
       }
     },
{
  "name": "ename",
   "Data": {
       "enamedetails":"details"
}
}]
}
```

I have generated getter setter methods for id,eid and tar but not sure how to generate for highlights. and convert the same into json using gson.

Getter setter Methods:

```
public class hello implements intt{

       @SerializedName("ID")
       private String ID = null;

       @SerializedName("Eid")
       private String Eid=null;

       @SerializedName("tar")
       private String tar=null;
/**
       * @return the Id
       */
       public String getId() {
              return Id;
       }

       /* (non-Javadoc)
       * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
       */
       @Override
       public String toString() {
              return "EDetails [ID=" + ID
                           + ", eid=" + eid+ ", tar=" + tar
                           + "]";
       }

       /**
       * @param Id the Id to set
       */
       public void setId(String Id) {
              this.Id= Id;
       }

       /**
       * @return the eid
       */
       public String geteid() {
              return eid;
       }

       /**
       * @param eid the eid to set
       */
       public void seteid(String eid) {
              this.eid= eid;
       }

       /**
       * @return the tar
       */
       public String gettar() {
              return tar;
       }

       /**
       * @param tar the tar to set
       */
       public void settar(String tar) {
              this.tar= tar;
       }
```

In implementation class,

```
edetails.setId("id1");
edetails.settar("pro");
edetails.seteid("eid1");
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String sDetails=gson.toJson(edetails);
```

Not sure how to do this for nested json class

Comment: Let's see some actual code. Otherwise, we cannot help.

Comment: You are almost there...Show us what you tried until now, so we can help you...

Answer (score 0):

The *highlights* is a list of objects, so you can do this:

```
 public class hello implements intt{
    //other parts of class
       List<Highlight> highlights;

       public void setHighlights(List<Highlight> highlights){
          this.highlights = highlights;
         }
    }
```

Where Highlight is a POJO like below:

```
public class Highlight{
  public String name;
  @SerializedName("Data")
  public Data data;
}
```

And the Data POJO:

```
public class Data{
  public String dataid;
  public String enamedetails;
}
```

Then you simply create a list, and call the *setHighlights* method.

Comment: Hi Kushtrim,  Thanks for the quick response, i tried implementing this yesterday, i was able to set the values, but i am not able add it in the list. Kindly help me with this, sorry,i am new to this development. TIA

Comment: @Deve1 Post you new code, so we can see what's wrong.