# how to get and display json array data from our auto generated pojo class?

Tags: android, json, pojo

I have searched all over the internet but i am not able to parse my json array from pojo class.Application is getting crashed again and again.Please can anyone tell me how to parse and display json array from a complex json response.This is my JSON response.
From this i want to parse my department name,description, product name and category list.

```
{ "departmentAndCategory": [
{
  "departmentName": "Apparels",
  "departmentDescription": "Apparels",
  "storeId": null,
  "categoryList": [],
  "id": 1
},
{
  "departmentName": "Footwear",
  "departmentDescription": "footwear for men,women and kids",
  "storeId": null,
  "categoryList": [
    {
      "departmentId": 10,
      "categoryName": "Footwear",
      "categoryDescription": "Footwear for men,women and kids",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    },
    {
      "departmentId": 10,
      "categoryName": "Vehicles",
      "categoryDescription": "Two and Four wheelers",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    }
  ],
  "id": 10
},
{
  "departmentName": "Appliances",
  "departmentDescription": "TV,Washing Machines,Refrigerators etc.",
  "storeId": null,
  "categoryList": [
    {
      "departmentId": 11,
      "categoryName": "Appliances",
      "categoryDescription": "Appliances for home like TV,Washing Machines,Refrigerators etc.",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    },
    {
      "departmentId": 11,
      "categoryName": "Vehicles",
      "categoryDescription": "Two and Four wheelers",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    }
  ],
  "id": 11
},
{
  "departmentName": "Electronics",
  "departmentDescription": "Mobile Phones,Routers etc.",
  "storeId": null,
  "categoryList": [
    {
      "departmentId": 12,
      "categoryName": "Electronics",
      "categoryDescription": "Electrnocs for personal use like Mobile Phones,Routers etc.",
      "parentCategoryId": null
    }
  ],
  "id": 12
},
{
  "departmentName": "Home & Furniture",
  "departmentDescription": "All your Home & Furniture needs",
  "storeId": null,
  "categoryList": [],
  "id": 2
},
{
  "departmentName": "test",
  "departmentDescription": "test",
  "storeId": null,
  "categoryList": [],
  "id": 14
},
{
  "departmentName": "apparels",
  "departmentDescription": "apparels",
  "storeId": null,
  "categoryList": [],
  "id": 15
},
{
  "departmentName": "Levi`s Tshirt",
  "departmentDescription": "Levi`s Tshirt",
  "storeId": null,
  "categoryList": [],
  "id": 16
}],"productsAndDeals": [ {
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "Levis T-shirt",
  "productDescription": "A good fabric from levis",
  "productPrice": 2000,
  "productInStock": 7,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Clothes",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 1
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "skin-fit",
  "productDescription": "best blue jeans",
  "productPrice": 1000,
  "productInStock": 15,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Jeans",
  "dealList": [
    {
      "dealImage": "dev.beacon.interrait.com/resources/deal-1.jpg",
      "productsId": 2,
      "categoryId": 1,
      "expiryDate": null,
      "discountPercentage": 60,
      "discountAmount": 600,
      "isActive": "False",
      "dealNotes": null,
      "dealName": "Massive discount on skin fit jeans",
      "id": 1
    }
  ],
  "id": 2
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "bell-bottoms",
  "productDescription": "best blue jeans",
  "productPrice": 1200,
  "productInStock": 15,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Jeans",
  "dealList": [
    {
      "dealImage": "dev.beacon.interrait.com/resources/deal-1.jpg",
      "productsId": 3,
      "categoryId": 1,
      "expiryDate": null,
      "discountPercentage": 40,
      "discountAmount": 480,
      "isActive": "False",
      "dealNotes": null,
      "dealName": "Massive discount on bell bottoms",
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
  "id": 3
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "curve-jeans",
  "productDescription": "best blue jeans",
  "productPrice": 1200,
  "productInStock": 15,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Jeans",
  "dealList": [
    {
      "dealImage": "dev.beacon.interrait.com/resources/deal-1.jpg",
      "productsId": 4,
      "categoryId": 1,
      "expiryDate": null,
      "discountPercentage": 50,
      "discountAmount": 600,
      "isActive": "False",
      "dealNotes": null,
      "dealName": "Massive discount on curve jeans",
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
  "id": 4
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "Aman",
  "productDescription": "",
  "productPrice": 1000,
  "productInStock": 12,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Tshirt",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 6
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "T-shirts for Men",
  "productDescription": "New T-shirt collection",
  "productPrice": 599,
  "productInStock": 0,
  "productAvailability": "Product not in stock",
  "title": "T-shirts",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 7
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "abvgc",
  "productDescription": "askkkdd",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 1,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "dddrr",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 19
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "top",
  "productDescription": "askkkdd",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 1,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "dddrr",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 20
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "topsss",
  "productDescription": "askkkdfffd",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 1,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "dddrr",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 21
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "topsss",
  "productDescription": "askkkdfffd",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 1,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "dddrr",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 22
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "sample",
  "productDescription": "sample",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 10,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Product",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 23
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "sample",
  "productDescription": "sample",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 10,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Product",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 24
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "sample",
  "productDescription": "sample",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 10,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Product",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 25
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "mobile",
  "productDescription": "smartphones",
  "productPrice": null,
  "productInStock": 1,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "dddrr",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 30
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "Apples",
  "productDescription": "fresh apples from farm",
  "productPrice": 150,
  "productInStock": 90,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Red apples",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 31
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "slippers and jackets",
  "productDescription": "Slip Ons",
  "productPrice": 210,
  "productInStock": 45,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Liberty slippes",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 110
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "glucose",
  "productDescription": "glucone D",
  "productPrice": 60,
  "productInStock": 123,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Glucose for health",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 117
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "jackets",
  "productDescription": "rugged jackets",
  "productPrice": 210,
  "productInStock": 45,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "Liberty slippes",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 121
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "Stationary",
  "productDescription": "pens,pencil",
  "productPrice": 10,
  "productInStock": 100,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "--",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 127
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "bat",
  "productDescription": "cricket bats",
  "productPrice": 500,
  "productInStock": 20,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "games for kids",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 128
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "ball",
  "productDescription": "cricket bats",
  "productPrice": 500,
  "productInStock": 20,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "games for kids",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 130
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "sports",
  "productDescription": "cricket bats",
  "productPrice": 500,
  "productInStock": 20,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "games for kids",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 131
},
{
  "imageName": null,
  "smallImage": null,
  "productName": "garden",
  "productDescription": "axe",
  "productPrice": 500,
  "productInStock": 20,
  "productAvailability": "Product is available",
  "title": "-",
  "dealList": [],
  "id": 132
}
```

]
}

Comment: Use JsonObject Class to parse this json.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203125/how-to-create-a-java-object-for-the-nested-json-using-pojo-class

Comment: i have used this "Type type = new TypeToken<List<DepartmentAndCategory>>(){}.getType();" to parse my departandcategory array but i am not able to display the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use following classes to parse your Response:
 Create Two classes:
  1. DepartmentAndCategory
  2. ProductsAndDeals

//DepartmentAndCategory class

public class DepartmentAndCategory {

```
private List<CategoryList> categoryList;

private String departmentDescription;

private String departmentName;

public DepartmentAndCategory(String departmentName,String departmentDescription,
                             List<CategoryList> categoryList){
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
    this.departmentDescription = departmentDescription;
    this.categoryList = categoryList;
}

public List<CategoryList> getCategoryList() {
    return categoryList;
}

public void setCategoryList(List<CategoryList> categoryList) {
    this.categoryList = categoryList;
}

public String getDepartmentDescription ()
{
    return departmentDescription;
}

public void setDepartmentDescription (String departmentDescription)
{
    this.departmentDescription = departmentDescription;
}

public String getDepartmentName ()
{
    return departmentName;
}

public void setDepartmentName (String departmentName)
{
    this.departmentName = departmentName;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [ categoryList = "+categoryList+", departmentDescription = "+departmentDescription+", departmentName = "+departmentName+"]";
}
```

}

//ProductsAndDeals class

public class ProductsAndDeals {
    private String productName;

```
public ProductsAndDeals(){}

public ProductsAndDeals(String productName){
    this.productName = productName;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{

    return "ClassPojo [productName = "+productName+"]";
}
```

}

// Then main class to parse the response

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    List<DepartmentAndCategory> departmentAndCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ProductsAndDeals> productsAndDealsList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int i=0;
        //Pass your response String here
        ParseResponse(Response.RESPONSE);
        String[] departNameArray = new String[departmentAndCategoryList.size()];

        //printing Department Name, Department Description and Category List
        for (DepartmentAndCategory list : departmentAndCategoryList){
            Log.e(TAG,"Departname : "+list.getDepartmentName());
            Log.e(TAG,"DepartDesc :"+list.getDepartmentDescription());
            departNameArray[i] = list.getDepartmentName();
            i++;
            for (CategoryList list1 : list.getCategoryList()){
                Log.e(TAG,"departmentId "+list1.getDepartmentId());
                Log.e(TAG,"categoryName "+list1.getCategoryName());
                Log.e(TAG,"categoryDescription "+list1.getCategoryDescription());
                Log.e(TAG,"parentCategoryId "+list1.getParentCategoryId());
            }
        }

        //departName array
        for (int j=0;j<departNameArray.length;j++){
            Log.e(TAG,"DepartName : "+departNameArray[j]);
        }

        //printing Product Name
        for (ProductsAndDeals dealsList : productsAndDealsList){
            Log.e(TAG,"Product name : "+dealsList.getProductName());
        }

    }

    private void ParseResponse(String response){

        try {
            JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray department = rootObj.optJSONArray("departmentAndCategory");

            for (int i=0;i<department.length();i++){
                List<CategoryList> mCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();

                JSONObject departmentObj = department.getJSONObject(i);
                String departName = departmentObj.getString("departmentName");
                String departDesc = departmentObj.getString("departmentDescription");

                JSONArray categoryArray = departmentObj.optJSONArray("categoryList");

                    for (int j=0;j<categoryArray.length();j++){
                        JSONObject categoryObj = categoryArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        String departId = categoryObj.getString("departmentId");
                        String categoryName = categoryObj.getString("categoryName");
                        String categoryDescription = categoryObj.getString("categoryDescription");
                        String parentCategoryId = categoryObj.getString("parentCategoryId");
                        CategoryList categoryList = new CategoryList(categoryName,categoryDescription,
                                departId,parentCategoryId);
                        mCategoryList.add(categoryList);
                    }

                DepartmentAndCategory departmentAndCategory = new DepartmentAndCategory(
                        departName,departDesc,mCategoryList
                );

                departmentAndCategoryList.add(departmentAndCategory);
            }

            JSONArray product = rootObj.optJSONArray("productsAndDeals");
            for (int i=0;i<product.length();i++){
                JSONObject productObj = product.getJSONObject(i);
                String productName = productObj.getString("productName");
                ProductsAndDeals productsAndDeals = new ProductsAndDeals(productName);

                productsAndDealsList.add(productsAndDeals);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: it si showing a null pointer exception on 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference. what does that mean?

Comment: I just checked my code with the response you have provided and it is printing all the mentioned details correctly.
Here for your reference output of my code with the given response:
Departname : Apparels
DepartDesc :Apparels
Departname : Footwear
DepartDesc :footwear for men,women and kids
departmentId 10
categoryName Footwear
categoryDescription Footwear for men,women and kids
parentCategoryId null
departmentId 10
categoryName Vehicles
categoryDescription Two and Four wheelers
parentCategoryId null

and so on...

Comment: sorry for the late response. The values are coming in the logcat but i am unable to put these values in a listview getDepartmentName return type is String. only the last deptname is coming.

Comment: sorry I not not able to understand what problem you are facing. can you explain in detail.

Comment: like you have displayed department name and description in log file.I want to display it in a listview but i am facing problem in casting it to a string array as getdepartmentname return type is String.

Comment: Log.e(TAG,"Departname : "+list.getDepartmentName()); I want to display this part in a listview getting alll the department names.

Comment: could you also tell me how cani open categories when the user clicks on the department name, its respective categories are open then?

Comment: Didn't get your question?? please expalin

Comment: when displaying all the department names in a listview, on clicking on any department , alll the categories should come in a listView of the respective department?

Comment: It's very easy buddy if you see the structure of departmentAndCategoryList you have department name and its category list at everyposition. So based on the departmnet name clicked just fetch the categorylist and show it into the listview

Comment: if for some department name category list is coming as an empty array, then what condition check should we put while taking values from the list after the parseResponse is finish and then for loop is called??

Comment: Department name is stored in a string check if string is null or not and category list is an array you can check if it's length is greater than 0 or not.

Comment: and when i want to display category name the app is getting crashed on for(CategoryList list1 : list.getCategoryList()).. and it is showing that attempt to invoke interface method on a null object refrence.. i am not able to figure out that what i am doing wrong over here?

Comment: Because you have written wrong code, if you want to display category name write list.getCategoryName

Comment: but first i have to call getCategory list method then only i can use getCategory name? as category list is an array containing category name

Comment: first check whether categorylist is there null or not for particular JSON object

Comment: can you please tell me how to take product name ,product price, product description and display it in a text view??

Comment: Just add two more parameters in ProductAndDeals class I am only taking productName add productPrice and productDesc in it and then in JsonArray of MainActivity along with product name save additional two parameters also